# how to style text created by Paint Android

Tags: android

I have been trying to figure out how to style the text created by Paint object in android. I placed the text onto imageView just like 'Watermark.'
However, it looks really fuzzy. I want to style this text better.

Would you please help me to style this text more nicely? 
e.g. I can put the outer line that surrounds the text. 
Please refer to the picture on the link below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ipipksb5lx25ywp/20150325_172802.jpg?dl=0

Here is what I am trying to display the text just like above the link..

```
    TextPaint paintText = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paintText.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paintText.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paintText.setTextSize(13);
    paintText.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), OPENSANS_SEMIBOLD);
    paintText.setTypeface(face);
    paintText.setShader(new LinearGradient(3, 3, 3, 3, Color.GREEN, Color.WHITE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));

    Rect rectText = new Rect();
    paintText.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), rectText);

    //set location of the watermark text....
    canvas.drawText(text, 10, 20, paintText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

Change

```
    paintText.setTypeface(face);

TO

    paintText.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif", Typeface.BOLD));
```

Comment: :Thanks for your answer but it's not really helpful though. Any ideas?

Comment: Well this is what i was able to think of. 
Have you solved this issue? If so How?